# Error using Requests in a frozen app

Tags: python, python-requests, cx-freeze, esky

I am trying to use the excelent requests library in a frozen app. The code works fine when interpreted, but it stops working when I generate the dist executable.

I tried this solution, but it is not working ([Requests library: missing file after cx_freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157502/requests-library-missing-file-after-cx-freeze))

My setup.py file:

```
import esky.bdist_esky
from esky.bdist_esky import Executable as Executable_Esky
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from myapp import VERSION
import requests.certs

packages = [
    'PIL',
    '_winreg',
    'esky',
    ]

includes = [
    'PySide',
    'sys',
    'os',
    'datetime',
    'threading',
    'Queue',
    'uuid',
    'requests',
]

excludes = [
    'TKinter',
    'tcl',
    'ttk',
]

include_files =["icon-16px.ico",
                "icon-32px.ico",
                "logo-t-160x56.png",
                ]

setup(
    scripts = [
        Executable_Esky(
            "myapp.py",
            gui_only = False,
            icon = "icon-16px.ico",
        ),
    ],
    data_files = include_files,
    options={"build_exe":
                 {"packages":packages,
                  "includes": includes,
                  "include_files": include_files + [(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')],
                  "excludes": excludes,
                  "optimize": 2,
                  "icon":"icon-16px.ico",
                 },
             "bdist_esky":{
                 'freezer_module':"cxfreeze",
                 'includes': includes,
                 'excludes': excludes,
             },
    },
    executables = [Executable(script="myapp.py",base="Win32GUI")],
)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fernando\Dropbox\the all-seeing boss\myapp_client\testes\cx
_freeze\qt_gui\interface_qt.py", line 45, in login
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 383, in reques
t
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509
certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557#issuecomment-6420819 looks applicable.

Comment: Yep, that thread has the (probable) answer. requests is looking for an SSL certificate file, but when frozen, you need to include a copy of the file and tell requests where it is.

Comment: I tried import the certificate file, but it didn't work, I'll keep working on that, thank you guys for this tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this following this issue on github(https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557#issuecomment-6420819). Thank you Martjin Pieters for this tip.

First of all, I put the cacert.pem file in my project's folder and then I included this in the frozen app:

```
include_files =["icon-16px.ico",
                "icon-32px.ico",
                "logo-t-160x56.png",
                "cacert.pem",
                ]

setup(
    scripts = [
        Executable_Esky(
            "myapp.py",
            gui_only = False,
            icon = "icon-16px.ico",
        ),
    ],
    data_files = include_files,
    options={"build_exe":
                 {"packages":packages,
                  "includes": includes,
                  "include_files": include_files,
                  "excludes": excludes,
                  "optimize": 2,
                  "icon":"icon-16px.ico",
                 },
             "bdist_esky":{
                 'freezer_module':"cxfreeze",
                 'includes': includes,
                 'excludes': excludes,
             },
    },
    executables = [Executable(script="myapp.py",base="Win32GUI")],
)
```

And for the last you must indicate this certificate in each POST or GET using `requests`, like this:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, verify = os.path.join(appdata,'cacert.pem'))
```

XD

Answer (score 2):

or you can use

```
import requests.certs
build_exe_options = {"include_files":[(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')]}
```