# python requests and cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-requests, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze a python app that depends on requests, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 630, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Looks like it is having trouble finding the ssl certificate with the executable. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157502/requests-library-missing-file-after-cx-freeze) which seems to be the same problem, but I am not able to figure out how they got it to work. The main problem seems to be that the certificate bundled by requests is not copied over to the compressed library. So it seems that I will have to force cx_freeze to bundle the certificates and then point to it from my script.

Starting with this simple script everything works fine:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://yourapihere.com")
print(r.json())
```

Then if I add the certificate file I stat getting errors:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://yourapihere.com", cert=requests.certs.where())
print(r.json())
```

-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 480, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 906, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 637, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2155)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 504, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2155)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://yourapihere.com", cert=requests.certs.where())
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2155)
```

I guess I am using it [correctly](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), but cant really figure out why it is not working. I guess that after fixing this I can continue and add the certificate to the cx_freeze bundle, something like:

example.py:

```
import os
import requests

cert = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(requests.__file__),'cacert.pem')
r = requests.get("https://yourapihere.com", cert=cert)
print(r.json())
```

setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import requests.certs
build_exe_options = {"zip_includes":[(requests.certs.where(),'requests/cacert.pem')]}

executables = [
    Executable('example.py')
]

setup(
      executables=executables
      )
```

if someone could give me a tip it would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your frozen code `requests.__file__` won't point to a real file, because the module is inside a zip file. See [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the FAQ.

Comment: I double checked that and requests.__file__ points to the zip file. So I guess that is fine.

Comment: No, because it can't just open `.../library.zip/requests/cacert.pem`. That path needs to point to a file that it can open and read.

Comment: That first error is not using freeze, just running normal.

Comment: I have a feeling that path should be passed as the `verify` parameter - `cert` appears to be something different.

Comment: Yup you are right =) Now that part works. What about putting it inside the frozen exe? any tips?

Comment: Have a look at [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the docs to see how to get the path to the application directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to get this to work:

- Explicitly tell requests where the certificate are
- Tell cx_freeze to also get the certificate file when "building"
- have the code to use the proper certificate file when frozen

test.py:

```
import os
import sys

import requests

# sets the path to the certificate file
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # if frozen, get embeded file
    cacert = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'cacert.pem')
else:
    # else just get the default file
    cacert = requests.certs.where()

# remember to use the verify to set the certificate to be used
# I guess it could also work with REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE, but I have not tried
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify=cacert)

print(r)
```

setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import requests
import sys

executable = Executable( script = "test.py" )

# Add certificate to the build
options = {
    "build_exe": {
        'include_files' : [(requests.certs.where(), 'cacert.pem')]
    }
}

setup(
    version = "0",
    requires = ["requests"],
    options = options,
    executables = [executable]
)
```

to build it, just:

```
$ python setup.py build
```

If successful you should see:

```
$ test
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this comment from another thread that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25239701/3935084

### Summary below:

> You can also use environment variable "REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE" (as said http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)
>
> It's much simpler than correcting all your requests:

```
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "cacert.pem")
```

Comment: Doing it based on `os.getcwd()` will only work if you run the program from the directory containing that file. If you make a shortcut and run it from somewhere else, it won't find that file. The FAQ has [an entry](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) about how to find data files relative to your exe.