# py2exe "requests" module missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-requests, py2exe

I don't know why I can't import package `requests`.

If I execute the script that needs `requests` library, it crashes obviously.

Web of requests library:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Version Py2exe 0.9.2.2

Version Python 3.4.3

I tried to use other options of py2exe as like `-i requests` I've even tried using the `setup.py` form, but I can't make it work.

```
py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe script.py --bundle-files 3

  24 missing Modules
  ------------------
? Cookie                              imported from requests.compat
? OpenSSL                             imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? Queue                               imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
? _abcoll                             imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? backports                           imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? certifi                             imported from requests.certs
? cookielib                           imported from requests.compat
? dummy_thread                        imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? ndg                                 imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? netbios                             imported from uuid
? pyasn1                              imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? simplejson                          imported from requests.compat
? thread                              imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? urllib.getproxies                   imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass                 imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote                        imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote_plus                   imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote                      imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote_plus                 imported from requests.compat
? urllib.urlencode                    imported from requests.compat, requests.packages.urllib3.request
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
? win32wnet                           imported from uuid
Building 'dist\script.exe'.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `python-request` for python 3  because it seams to me not: `Queue`, `thread` are only in Python 2

Comment: As the previous comment hints, `py2exe` may be confused by the fact that you've got both Python 2.x & 3.x installed. When you have multiple versions of Python one your system, you have to properly install the appropriate version of any extension module you want to into the proper one.

Comment: Python-request support both versions in the same package.
I tried to use py2exe in a pc that only have python 3, but happens the same

Answer (score 0):

If your program crashes with 
'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
the issue isn't missing modules, it's a missing file needed for SSL verification, 'cacert.pem'.

Someone explained how to solve this problem in this thread - 
[Requests library: missing file after cx_freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157502/requests-library-missing-file-after-cx-freeze)

I switched to cx_freeze from py2exe because I found it easier to deal with this missing file issue in cx_freeze.

Here's my full cx_freeze code, showing how to fully implement the solution described in the other StackOverflow thread, which will resolve this 'cacert.pem' issue.  I'm sure the solution is the same in py2exe, you'd just need to find the py2exe equivalent of the cx_freeze 'include_files'.  Maybe someone who knows could chime in to help.

Here's the setup.py file -

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import requests.certs

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

build_exe_options = {"include_files":[(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')]}

setup(name='MyProgramName',
      version='1.0',
      description='ProgramDescription',
      options={"build_exe":build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable('myScript.py',base=base)])
```

And now everywhere in your script where you make a request to a SSL server, you must add a 'verify' argument, and direct it to the 'cacert.pem' file.

```
r = requests.post('https://wherever.com', verify='cacert.pem')
```

or if you don't want SSL verification

```
r = requests.post('https://wherever.com', verify=False)
```

The issue is that 'verify' is set to 'True' by default, so that sends it looking for a cacert.pem file which doesn't exist.

I kept the .pem file in the same directory as the executable and was able to link to it directly, verify='cacert.pem'.  If this doesn't work for you, or you want to put it in another directory, there are solutions for getting the cwd of your exe file in the other StackOverflow thread.