# problems with importing `requests` when using py2exe

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-import, py2exe

#### TL;DR

Importing the `requests` library fails within a Python3 project when frozen with `py2exe`.
The unfrozen project works.
The problem seems to be related to relative imports within the `requests` module.

#### long description

I've created a little project using Python3, and would like to turn it into an executable for w32.
The project depends on `PySide` and `requests` (2.13.0; actually this is a secondary dependency of the used `pyapi-gitlab` package).
All dependencies have been installed via `pip3`.
Python version is *3.4.4* (since PySide doesn't support any later versions of Py3).
I'm using `py2exe 0.9.2.2`.

Everything  (e.g. importing and using `PySide`) works great, but the `import requests` deep inside fails.

Here's a somewhat minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()

import sys
print("Python: %s" % (sys.version,))

try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    log.fatal("failed to import 'requests'", exc_info=True)
```

When I run this from the cmdline, I get:

```
E:\p2e> python p2e.py
Python: 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
E:\p2e>
```

Nice.
The following minimal `setup.py` is supposed to turn this into an exe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['p2e.py'])
```

Doing the actual conversion gives a number of "missing modules" warnings:

```
E:\p2e> python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  24 missing Modules                 
  ------------------                 
? Cookie                              imported from requests.compat
? OpenSSL                             imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? Queue                               imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
? _abcoll                             imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? backports                           imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? certifi                             imported from requests.certs
? chardet                             imported from requests.packages
? cookielib                           imported from requests.compat
? cryptography                        imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? idna                                imported from requests.models, requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? netbios                             imported from uuid
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? simplejson                          imported from requests.compat
? six                                 imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? socks                               imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks
? urllib.getproxies                   imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass                 imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote                        imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote_plus                   imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote                      imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote_plus                 imported from requests.compat
? urllib.urlencode                    imported from requests.compat
? urllib3                             imported from requests.packages
? win32wnet                           imported from uuid
Building 'dist\p2e.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
E:\p2e>
```

I routinely ignore these warnings, and run the generated exe:

```
E:\p2e> dist\p2e.exe
CRITICAL:root:failed to import 'requests'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves import queue
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p2e.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'
Python: 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
E:\p2e>
```

I'm totally puzzled.

It seems that the `requests` package does some import magic to
- support both included 3rd-party libs (`urllib`) and libs installed by package managers.
- support both Py2 and Py3 (using a local copy of `six`)

Both seem to create problems.

I can amend the `urllib3` problem, by patching `requests` to only search for that package in relative paths (even though the original code does the same, only enclosed by a `try/catch` that catches any `ImportError` and then falls back to import globally.)

I have no idea how to fix the `import queue` problem.

And after all, it *is* working properly when I run the script in the Py3 interpreter.

#### NOTE

There's a similar (maybe the same) issue, but it doesn't include that much information: [py2exe "requests" module missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156802)

Comment: `queue` is a standard-library module in Python 3. If Py2exe is not including it, that sounds like a bug in Py2exe

Comment: @sigmavirus24 you are of course right about standard-librariness of `queue` (I removed the line stating otherwise in the Q).

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that importing queue fails and so importing urllib3 fails as well.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 indeed, you are right (again!); adding an explicit `--includes queue` to the py2exe-args fixes the import. if you could turn that into an answer, I will *accept* it.

Comment: I'm glad *we* figured it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like urllib3 tries to import the `queue` module which fails. When that fails, requests fails to import `urllib3.

To force py2exe to include the `queue` module, use `--includes queue` when you invoke it.