# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' on python 3.6.7

Tags: python, firebase, cx-freeze

I'm making a script that receives some args and use these args to manipulate a Firebase Realtime Database.

When I run the script on cmd (I'm on a Windows 10 computer) by typing `mpython myScript.py arg1 arg2 ...` it works fine. But when I use cx_Freeze to build my .exe it says that there are modules missing

```
Missing modules:
? Cookie imported from requests.compat
? OpenSSL.SSL imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? OpenSSL.crypto imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? StringIO imported from requests.compat, six, urllib3.packages.six
....
? urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse imported from 
urllib3.poolmanager, urllib3.request
? urlparse imported from requests.compat
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this 
platform.
```

And it also shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\engenharia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\engenharia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Api2.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\engenharia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "C:\Users\engenharia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 20, in <module>
    import google.auth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

My `setup.py`

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup ( 
    name = "pyFirebase",
    version = "1.1",
    executables = [Executable("pyFirebase.py")]
)
```

My imports on `pyFirebase.py` (not showing the whole program because it's from my job, I can't, sorry)

```
import sys
import os

import datetime

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

from random import randint
```

And my way of handling with the args

```
if(len(sys.argv) == 5):
    var1 = args[1]
```

I did a test using just the args and building the .exe and it worked, so probably the issue is with the modules or with my environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: try to modify your `setup.py` as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_files = []
packages = ['google']
build_exe_options = {'include_files': include_files,
                     'packages': packages}

setup ( 
    name = "pyFirebase",
    version = "1.1",
    options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("pyFirebase.py")]
)
```

`google` uses `requests`, you'll find additional information on how to use `requests` with `cx_Freeze` in [Requests library: missing SSL handshake certificates file after cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15157502/8516269).

You might further need to add any necessary file (license file, certificate, ...?) to the `include_files` list.

As far as the `Missing modules` list reported by `cx_Freeze` is concerned, this is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: I tried to `import google` but still getting the same error. 
Not necessarily a problem, but unfortunately in this case it was a problem. Nothing works although the .exe is executed.

Comment: @HenriqueZanferrari Do you get the same error or the .exe is executed? This statement is not clear to me. Anyway, I've edited my answer with a suggestion which might be better and added further information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the python version to 3.7.2 and using pyinstaller (wich I've tried before and also didn't worked) instead of cx_freeze.

Don't know why, but its working now.