# Python, AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.bigquery' has no attribute 'Client' after cx_Freeze build

Tags: python, google-bigquery, cx-freeze

I'm trying to use cx_Freeze to create an executable of a script which loads an .sql query from the same folder, executes it on a BigQuery DB and returns a .csv of the retrieved data.

```
  This is what the 'conda list' command gives me:
  google-api-core           1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
  google-auth               1.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
  google-cloud-bigquery     1.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge  
  google-cloud-core         0.28.1                     py_0    conda-forge
  google-resumable-media    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
  googleapis-common-protos  1.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
```

The script crashes in the first lines (KEY and PROJECT_ID are specified in the script but not pasted for security reasons)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(KEY, project=PROJECT_ID)
```

My setup.py for cx_Freeze looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='output_script', executables = [Executable("my_script.py")], version="1.0.0",
options={
         "build exe":{"packages":["google.cloud.bigquery, google.cloud.bigquery.client"]}})
```

The build executes successfully, however when I run my_script.exe in the build folder I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "my_script.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "my_script.py", line 7, in queryBigQ
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.bigquery' has no attribute 'Client'
```

Tried reinstalling and updating all Google packages but no success. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to run your script successfully before freezing it?

It looks like your local development environment is missing the bigquery library. Make sure that you create a [virtualenv](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv) and [install bigquery library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) in it.

Test the connection to BigQuery with a simple script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

QUERY = (
    'SELECT * FROM `[PROJECT_ID].[BQ_INSTANCE].[BQ_TABLE]`'
)
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
rows = query_job.result()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
client = Client.from_service_account_json(KEY, project=PROJECT_ID)
```

or maybe

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
client = Client.from_service_account_json(KEY, project=PROJECT_ID)
```

in your main script.

Try also to replace the `options` argument in your `setup.py` script by

```
options={"build exe": {"packages": ["google"]}}
```

Comment: Using the first and third snippet, now I get the following error: 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.bigquery.client'

Comment: @thatguyoverthere I don't know if this helps: `google` uses `requests`, you'll find additional information on how to use `requests` with `cx_Freeze` in [Requests library: missing SSL handshake certificates file after cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15157502/8516269). See also [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' on python 3.6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54188821/8516269).

Comment: @thatguyoverthere can you see in your local installation where the `Client` class is defined? It should be in a module `[path_to_site_packages]/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py`. Do you then see a corresponding file `lib/google/cloud/bigquery/client.pyc` in your build directory?

Comment: Yes, I can see the client.py file inside that path and the Client() class is defined in it. Actually the Python code runs fine with all the formats which I pasted and you gave. It's the cx_Freeze build which doesn't seem to package the correct items together.

Comment: I pasted a __init__.py file inside the Google library as it was missing. Previously it wasn't finding the package at all but no its only the Client thing.

Comment: Interesting. Is there also a `__init__.py` file in the subfolders packages `cloud` and `bigquery` as well? And maybe also `core`, `auth` and whatever else is used in the imports of these packages?

Comment: @thatguyoverthere Try also to add `"future"` to the `"packages"` list: `"packages": ["google", "future"]`

Comment: I've added `__init__.py` to all now tried adding `future` to `setup.py options`. Still the same error.