# cx_Freeze module with version number

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I would like to specify multiple modules to install by version number.

If this is my `setup.py`:

**How can I adjust the contents of the mods list to specify the version number?**

```python
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    import sys

    base = None

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        base = None


    executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]

    mods = ["cachetools==3.0.0",
    "pyexcel-xlsx==0.5.6",
    "idna"]

    packages = mods
    options = {
        'build_exe': {
            'packages':packages,
        },

    }

    setup(
        name = "file_rename",
        options = options,
        version = "1",
        description = 'renames pdf consent forms',
        executables = executables
    )
```

**Edit:**
The utilities.py file begins:

```
import os
from os.path import dirname
import json
import io
from google.cloud import vision
```

The error I get after applying the advice from @jpeg, is as follows:
[image: error]

My pip freeze is:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
cachetools==3.0.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
cx-Freeze==5.1.1
dialogflow==0.5.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-heroku==0.3.1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
google==2.0.1
google-api-core==1.6.0
google-auth==1.6.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-storage==1.13.1
google-cloud-vision==0.35.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5
grpcio==1.16.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
idna==2.7
image==1.5.27
jdcal==1.4
lml==0.0.7
numpy==1.15.4
openpyxl==2.5.12
packaging==19.0
pandas==0.23.4
pdf2image==1.1.0
Pillow==5.3.0
protobuf==3.6.1
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pyexcel==0.5.10
pyexcel-io==0.5.11
pyexcel-xlsx==0.5.6
pyparsing==2.3.1
pypng==0.0.19
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.7
requests==2.21.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.11.0
soupsieve==1.7.3
texttable==1.5.0
urllib3==1.24.1
whitenoise==3.3.1
wincertstore==0.2
XlsxWriter==1.1.2
```

The issue doesn't show itself when running the script normally, only after my exe is created and run, does an error appear.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from within the setup script (as far as I know). `cx_Freeze` makes an executable including exactly the same python version and configuration it is invoked with, see the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#freezing-for-other-platforms).

So you need to make a new python installation where you install all modules to the wished configuration using for example

```
python -m pip install cachetools==3.0.0
```

and invoke the setup script using for example

```
python setup.py build
```

where `python` stands for the python executable of your new installation.

You can have multiple python installations on a computer, each in a different directory and with different versions of the modules installed.

You could also use for example [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) to manage separate package installations for different projects, but it seems that using `cx_Freeze` from within a `virtualenv` needs some additional tweaking to work properly.

EDIT:

Try to replace the `packages` list by

```
packages = ['google']
```

in your setup script. See [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' on python 3.6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54188821/8516269)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did this, but I get the modulenotfound error. This doesn't happen when I run the script in my virtualenv without cx_freeze. That leads me to believe that the wrong versions are being used. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Please post the complete error message and which command you ran to get this error. See how to create a [mcve]. Otherwise there are few chances that anybody can understand what is exactly your problem and tries to help you.

Comment: @alwayscurious Thank you for the additions. I've added a corresponding suggestion to my answer. It would also be better if you could post the error message as text instead of an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)